# VS2015: breakpoint not worked Firefox/chrome/Edge

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

On debugging using Firefox(, chrome, Edge) simple JavaScript, the breakpoint (set the line 9 `var a = 4;`) don't seem to work. Is this specification?

#### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hello JavaScript</title>
    <script>
        var a = 4;
        var b = 2;
        window.alert(a+b);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
body content!
</body>
</html>
```

#### Environment

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
- Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
- Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01055
- Installed Version:Professional
- ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.21111.0
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
- ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
- Browser

  - IE 11.0.9600.18638
  - Firefox 52.0.2 (32bit)
  - Google Chrome 57.0.2987.133

#### Test result

[image: Test result on IE11 and Firefox]

Comment: This issue has been submitted as the feature request before: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6205061-provide-integrated-javascript-debugging-in-firefox, the VS2017 added some new features for it now.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks for the information, I will check VS2017 in the future.

Comment: You are welcome. I add the comment as the answer. So other community members could get this feature much more clearly and easily. Have a nice day:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old Visual Studio debugger allowed to debug both backend .NET code and client-side JavaScript running in the browser, but only IE browser was supported in the old VS versions like the VS2015.

If you really want to get this feature, I suggest you use the VS2017.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/21/client-side-debugging-of-asp-net-projects-in-google-chrome/

You can debug your JavaScript running in Chrome from inside Visual Studio.